# create new angular project stoped on /.gitkeep

Tags: angular, npm

I try to create new angular project with **ng new** command,
process started and waited on

> CREATE crm_ng/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
>
> Installing packages (npm) ...

I uninstalled **angular cli** again, cleaned cache and Install angular/cli again.
Try to create new agnular project with **ng new** but process stop on the above line,
I use

> Angular CLI: 16.0.1
>
> Node: 20.1.0 (Unsupported)
>
> Package Manager: npm 9.6.6
>
> OS: linux x64

Also when I use Proxy I  have the same problem and when I disabled proxy and run this command

> npm config rm proxy
>
> npm config rm https-proxy
> My problem exist.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? What version of `NodeJS` and `angular-cli` are you using?

Comment: Angular CLI: 16.0.1
Node: 20.1.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.6.6

Comment: I'd try using the latest LTF of NodeJS which is `18.16.0`. According to (this)[https://angular.io/guide/versions] document it should be compatible. Also, I'd not use any kind of proxy

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't support Node 20 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. I solved it by following steps. The development environment what i am using is as below -

OS - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,
Angular versions -

```
Angular CLI: 16.2.5
Node: 18.18.0
Package Manager: npm 
OS: linux x64
```

The steps what I follow to solve this is as below -

```
1. removed node_modules folder using command 'sudo rm -rf node_modules/'
2. execute the command 'sudo npm cache verify'
3. execute the commanf 'sudo npm install'
```

And finally run the command -

```
'sudo ng serve' and page avaialble on  'http://localhost:4200/'
```